# Working with android contacts

Tags: android, contacts

I need fetch information from all Android contacts:

- First name
- Last name
- Cell Phone
- Birth date

If the contact has two or more Cell phone numbers, it has to fit in the selection multiple times.

Now I use `ContentResolver.Query()` to get the required columns, but need more than once queries, rather than join tables.

How can I query multiple data fields from Android contacts?

I.e. i need execute something like SQL query:

```
SELECT
    dName.Data2 as [firstName]
    , dName.Data3 as [lastName]
    , dPhone.Data1 as [cellPhone]
FROM
   raw_contacts
INNER JOIN data as dName on dName.RAW_CONTACT_ID = Contacts._ID and dName.MIME_TYPE =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
INNER JOIN data as dPhone on dName.RAW_CONTACT_ID = Contacts._ID and dName.MIME_TYPE =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
```

Answer (score 1):

All the fields you've mentioned are eventually stored in the [`ContactsContract.Data`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) table, so no need for joins.
You just need to query all the data in Data table, while selecting your specific mimetypes ([phone](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html) and [event](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.html), which is birthdays), the full contact-name and contact-id, are stored for each mimetype as well:

```
Map<Long, List<String>> contacts = new HashMap<Long, List<String>>();

String[] projection = {Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1, Data.DATA2, Data.DATA3};
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1); // full name
    String mime = cur.getString(2); // phone / birthday
    String data = cur.getString(3); // the actual info, e.g. +1-212-555-1234

    String kind = "unknown";

    switch (mime) {
        case Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            kind = "phone"; 
            break;
        case Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            Event = "birthday";
            break;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + ", " + kind + " - " + data);

    // add info to existing list if this contact-id was already found, or create a new list in case it's new
    List<String> infos;
    if (contacts.containsKey(id)) {
        infos = contacts.get(id);
    } else {
        infos = new ArrayList<String>();
        infos.add("name = " + name);
        contacts.put(id, infos);
    }
    infos.add(kind + " = " + data);
}
```